# Wordpress Google Maps Plugin with markers and search engine

Tags: wordpress, maps, markers

I'm looking for a Wordpress Google Maps plugin with these functions:

- insert markers into maps with custom icon.
- I don't if this is possible, but I need insert a link in each marker to link to antoher website page.
- The user should be able to search and filter all markers by admin pre-configured categories or tags. The markers that match with the user search, should appear in the new map.

I tried some plugins like Maps Marker Pro (the best I found with a lot of options but I think it can't make a marker user search form), WP Google Maps, Mappress, Comprehensive GM plugin. But none of them seem to gather all the features I need.

Do you know any Maps Plugin with that functions?
Thanks
Victor

Comment: This is probably better suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ or http://wordpress.org/support/

Comment: Plugins recommendations are off topic at the wordpress stack exchange.  Why don't you take a shot at the code victor?  I bet people would be happy to help you with specific problems you run into instead of asking for a blanket ready built solution.

Answer (score 1):

We have developed a plugin that should be able to cater for all your requirements.

http://heroplugins.com/plugin/maps/

Regards,
Brett.

Comment: This is by far the most usable map plugin i've ever came across, well done guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a *plugin* that allows you to configure location categories and location attributes at the back end.
[This should do the job.](http://codecanyon.net/item/site-locator-map/7354406?WT.ac=category_item&WT.seg_1=category_item&WT.z_author=dalewpdevph)

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/agile-store-locator

Google Map WordPress Plugin with Google Search and Markers

Documentation and Demos

https://agilestorelocator.com/documentation/